# What is the "Malformed @foreach statement." error on Laravel's Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have this very basic setup...

**Users.php** (Laravel Livewire component)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class Users extends Component
{
    public $users;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        return view('livewire.users');
    }
}
```

**users.blade.php**

```php
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <div>{{ $user }}</div>
    <hr />
@foreach
```

However, it is throwing the exception `Illuminate \ Contracts\View\ViewCompilationException` with the following error:

```
Malformed @foreach statement.
```

Did I miss something? What does this error mean?

Comment: you are not closing the foreach and you are then opening another foreach with nothing to iterate ....

Comment: `@endforeach` i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your @foreach statement with @endforeach before starting new foreach. Same applies for @if @endif or any other Blade directives.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <div>{{ $user }}</div>
    <hr />
@endforeach
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops